# Animate using custom directive not working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

created a custom directive to extend v-show , v-showblock  is adding on true style: display: block;

The transitions/animations are working with v-show  but not with v-showblock, which is working without animation.

I simplified my code to focus on the issue:

```
<style>
 .fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity .5s
}
.fade-enter, .fade-leave-active {
  opacity: 0
}
</style>
<body>

<div id="demo">
  <button @click="toggle">Toggle</button>
    <transition name="fade">
    <p v-showblock="show">hello</p>
    </transition>
</div>



 Vue.directive('showblock',
         function (el, binding) {
            if (binding.value === true) {
                el.style.display = 'block';
            }
            else {
                el.style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    );
    new Vue({
      el: '#demo',
      data: {
        show: true
      },
      methods: {
         toggle: function() {
             this.show =!this.show;
         }
      }
    });
```

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle of it?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/w8ssj8np/1/ ; with v-show the transition is working, with v-showblock the transition(fade effect) is not working

Comment: I am not sure how this can be achieved using directive, I see use of transition [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/v2.1.3/src/platforms/web/runtime/directives/show.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't working because VueJS transitions work on elements within `<transition>` only in certain situations:

1. `v-if` state changes
2. `v-show` state changes
3. components

In your case you're attempting to hide/show using a custom directive `v-showblock`, which is unsupported. If you instead used `v-if` or `v-show` there, then the transition will work.

Read more in the [VueJS docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transitioning-Single-Elements-Components).